# node 'net' module ECONNREFUSED error

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I'm looking at this page: http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createconnection_options_connectionlistener

Running the code from the page:

```
var net = require('net');
var client = net.connect({port: 8124},
    function() { //'connect' listener
  console.log('client connected');
  client.write('world!\r\n');
});
client.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(data.toString());
  client.end();
});
client.on('end', function() {
  console.log('client disconnected');
});
```

and I'm getting the error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)

shell returned 8
```

version stuff:

```
~ % node --version
v0.10.25

~ % uname -a
Linux human1 3.13.0-031300-generic #201401192235 SMP Mon Jan 20 03:36:48 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've tried a lot of different ports and I'm positive node isn't already running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the net server you're trying to connect to running?

I tried this and it works for me:

net.js

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(client) {
    console.log('connected');
});

server.listen(8124);

var client = net.connect({port: 8124}, function() {
    console.log('client connected');
    client.write('world!\r\n');
});
client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
    client.end();
});
client.on('end', function() {
    console.log('client disconnected');
});
```

Run:

```
$ node net.js 
connected
client connected
```

Comment: Thanks. It's obvious now.