# How to fix the error "connect ECONNREFUSED"?

Tags: node.js

```
C:\Users\fc\Desktop\js-basics\Projects>node net.js
```

Gives this error:

```
  Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8085
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1056:14) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 8085
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node 'net' module ECONNREFUSED error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600144/node-net-module-econnrefused-error)

Comment: run successfully. how "  client.write('world!\r\n');" work?  bcz I get nothing on port:8124

Comment: 'Connection refused' means that nothing was listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways you can solve this issue.

1.You can kill port which is listening on 8085  `sudo killall node`

2.You can change the port number. Here's a working example:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!'); // This will serve your request to '/'.
});

app.listen(8000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 8000!');
 });
```

Comment: First not...........but second  run successfully. Thanks! @orvi

Comment: 'Connection refused' means that nothing was listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to. *Ergo* there is no listening port. Your first point does not make sense.